# Search on gridView does nothing

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql, database

I have a gridVIew which has a datasource of a table in Access database.

I want to add search functionality on this gridview. I added a textBox and search button. My Code is

```
protected void btnSearchService_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string SearchField = TextBox1.Text;
    string searchSQL = "SELECT * FROM LocalService WHERE ServiceName LIKE '%" + SearchField + "%'";

    SqlDataSource1.UpdateCommand = searchSQL;
    SqlDataSource1.Update();
}
```

But in browser when I click Search button, I see nothing happens. DO I have to add code on page load or somewhere?

Comment: Make sure you are binding the gridview after having filtered datasource.

Comment: Sure looks like you are binding this to the update command.  Not so much an update.  Updates change records.  Do the select bind the results to the data of the datasource.

Comment: Cool! I will check that. Let me try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It worked. I have replaced following lines

```
SqlDataSource1.UpdateCommand = searchSQL;
SqlDataSource1.Update();
```

with these lines

```
SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = searchSQL;
GridView1.DataBind();
```